# AngularJs Environment variables in Heroku Pipeline

Tags: angularjs, heroku-pipelines

I'm traying to configure an AngularJs/NodeJs app in a Heroku Pipeline. What I understand of a every DevOps Pipeline, the goal is avoid recompiling the app in every stage. For the Node API the Heroku suggestion is pretty clear: config vars. But for the AngularJs client -obvisly, config vars are for server side scripts- I haven't found any suggestion or good practice. Also, I've searched into the deep internet and what I found is that there is not a common issue. I've found [this](https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-to-configure-your-angular-application-without-a-rebuild/) well explained article and now I'm working on it, but what is hard to understand for me is: is not a common issue to avoid recompilation of Angular clients in stage-to production pipelines? Is there not a official proposal of AngularJs dev team to this situation?
My thougts are:
1- I'm misunderstanding something....or..
2- Promote to production Angular apps without recompiling is not a common issue.

Please, I'm new on Angular and I need some advice.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your effort?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41348751/heroku-pipeline-with-angular-2-environments/41349236#41349236

Comment: Thanks @yoni, I actually read your answer in that thread and it's pretty clear. But even in that thread there is no clear solution and your answser has only 4 likes.  Also, there is not an offcial documentation about this issue and googling it didn't help. This make me think that avoiding re-compiling Angular app in production is not a common good practice as I thinked (I wonder how many Angular apps are running into Heroku Pipelines right now....). Thanks again.

Comment: Recompiling Angular apps (or anything else for that matter) when promoting between pipeline phases basically defeats the whole point of pipelines, part of which is to promote an unmodified tested binary from development through staging to production. The way I personally deal with this issue in my pipeline apps is to have my Ionic/Angular client query the server for any pipeline-specific env vars (which can be set differently in each pipeline phase).

Answer (score 1):

refer the angular version you are using

[angular 4](https://youtu.be/jw1RtGJKIbw)

[angular 6](https://youtu.be/hE1i_LhL_Nc)

[angular 2](https://youtu.be/GgWvuBdatAM)

Follow these methods as shows

there is no short summary or spinet   to define process

Comment: Thanks @jackson but there videos only shows how to deploy Angular apps on Heroku without pipelines orchestration.